# How to remove gameobjects that have the same transform position as each other?

Tags: unity

If I have 4 copies of the same gameobject in my scene and they all have the exact same transform position as each other, how can I remove the 3 duplicates so that only one unique gameobject remains? This is what I tried so far...

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        RemoveDuplicate(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Path"));
    }
}

private void RemoveDuplicate(GameObject[] other)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Path").Length; i++)
    {
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Path")[i] == other[i]) continue;
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Path")[i].transform.position == other[i].transform.position)
        {
            Destroy(other[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

Comment: For future reference, it's better to edit a question rather than delete and re-post. The SE system considers a lot of deleted questions suspicious (or not high-quality contributions) so this can trigger temporary question bans in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `GameObject[] other` is the object you want to check against I would do something like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RemoveDupes : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Update ()
    {

        //I don't know where you get the object you want to test against from
        //so I have done it in the quickest simplest way possible 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //find the first object with the tag "Path" I'm using this as the position to compare against note 'FindGameObject' not Objects
            GameObject objectToTest = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Path");
            RemoveDuplicates(objectToTest);
        }
    }

    private void RemoveDuplicates(GameObject objectToTest)
    {
        //cache the array instead of calling it each time
        GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Path");

        //loop over each object in the array
        foreach (var obj in gameObjects)
        {
            //if the current objects position is the same as the object we are testing against
            if (obj.transform.position == objectToTest.transform.position)
            {
                //we should also make sure that the function doesn't compare the object against itself or you would have no cubes left
                if (obj != objectToTest)
                {
                    Destroy(obj);
                }
            }
        }

      }
}
```